# What query parameters should be set in Jenkins REST API to get all the jobs which executed on a slave?

Tags: jenkins, slave

I was trying to get all the jobs which executed within a year on a specific jenkins slave.This could later be made more dynamic by just replacing slave name to get job details corresponding to it.

Below is the Jenkins REST API call using which I tried but there was no attribute for jobs present in json:

```
<JENKINS_URL>/computer/<SLAVE_NAME>/api/json
```

Could someone please suggest any way to get all those jobs corresponding to each slave?

Answer (score 0):

As of what stands today.
You can get a build history of node from one of these three urls

```
https://jenkins/computer/<SLAVE_NAME>/rssAll
https://jenkins/computer/<SLAVE_NAME>/rssFailed
https://jenkins/computer/<SLAVE_NAME>/rssLatest
```

There already is an open issue in Jenkins Project
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44304
`node build history is missing REST API`

But based on the discussion in issues

- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42938
- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-38877

This might not be implemented at all.
Refer to the following comment for the reasons.
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-38877?focusedCommentId=373754&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-373754

> If you have a lot of historical builds,
> the performance will be abysmal (especially on HDDs) since an
> unbounded number of little XML files would need to be loaded from disk
> and deserialized into memory, then discarded shortly afterward once
> the system gets into a low memory condition. That is true of freestyle
> builds and would be worse still for Pipeline builds due to the more
> complex metadata. A supportable solution would need something like a
> database that gets updated when a build uses a node—not a difficult
> programming project at all, but logistically a problem since Jenkins
> currently lacks any kind of standardized database, so you would need
> to either initiate that effort, or do a one-off hack with some sort of
> text file stored in a node’s configuration directory.

Comment: https://jenkins/computer/<SLAVE_NAME>/rssAll
https://jenkins/computer/<SLAVE_NAME>/rssFailed
https://jenkins/computer/<SLAVE_NAME>/rssLatest

These give HTTP 404 and doesn't work at all.Maybe working specific to few jenkins instance only?

Comment: You can have a look at the RSS url below in the page https://jenkins/computer/<SLAVE_NAME>/builds

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I found that at the bottom of the page but still it gives below error for :

https://<JENKINS_SERVER>/computer/<SLAVE>/rssLatest and https://<JENKINS_SERVER>/computer/<SLAVE>/rssAll

HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.24

Comment: Only thing now remain to see is the jenkins error log and apache log... Then you can pin point the reason for not found status....